# How to set sonar url commonly for all the multibranch pipeline jobs(created via bitbucket organization job) commonly?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using organization "Organizational Folder" in jenkins and able to create multibranch pipeline jobs for all my repos available in my organization folder in bitbucket.

Each of the repos contains Jenkinsfile because of which the job gets created. Now I am stuck at a point, I want to publish sonar report of all the repos but it is trying to publish at sonar default url. One solution I am aware of is to provide sonar url and login credentials in each of the Jenkinsfile. But I don't want to do that as I will have to make changes in more than 50 repos.

I am using shared instance of Jenkins, thus, does not have admin access to configure settings.xml for maven.

Is there any way by which I can pass sonar url and credentials to all the multibranch pipeline jobs via configuration in "Organizational Folder" or at the folder level where I have admin access

Answer (score 1):

You can define sonarQube server in `environment` section of jenkinsfile and also create token on sonarQube and add it in credentials of jenkins and use it like this

```
environment {
  SONAR_URL = "https://YOUR_SONARQUBE_URL"
  SONAR_TOKEN = credentials('ID_OF_YOUR_CREDENTIALS')
}

stage("Run SonarQube Analysis") {
      steps {
        script {
           sh 'mvn clean package sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_URL -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_TOKEN -Dsonar.profile="Sonar way"'
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: As per my understanding ,configure system is available if we have admin rights over the jenkins. But we don't have admin rights on jenkins. We are using shared jenkins in the organization and we have one folder created where we can place our jobs

Comment: ok then you can directly use the sonarQUbe url in the environment section and use it. I will edit my answer so you can use that

Comment: That is where the issue is my organization folder has about 50 repositories, I do not want to change Jenkinsfile of all those 50 repos

Comment: Then this is not possible you do not have configure system access and you do not wnat to edit jenkinsfile then there is no way you can tell jekins to point to sonarQube server.